# Openshift throws '404 Not Found'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, openshift

I just set up this application with PHP 5.4 and Code Igniter on OpenShift and when I try to access the root of my page says

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at pombadapaz-upsites.rhcloud.com Port
>   80

The URL is http://pombadapaz-upsites.rhcloud.com/

And this is what I got in my .htaccess (though it's not important because I just commented everything, pushed and the error persists)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Anyone would say why?

Comment: Can you access any hard file on your hosting ? And does index.php exists on hosting root ? When I navigate to http://pombadapaz-upsites.rhcloud.com/index.php web server returns 404 too.

Comment: exactly. it does exist and i cant access the index.php

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official OpenShift CodeIgniter quickstart,](https://github.com/openshift/CodeIgniterQuickStart/) you should have your .htaccess looking like this (including CodeIgn best practice of removing the index.php from the URL):

```
RewriteEngine on

# removes trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: no ti still doesnt work. I created a pombadapaz2-upsites.rhcloud.com/ to make I hadn't done anything wrong at the first time. but I still can't manage to make it work. 404 persists

Comment: @VictorFerreira what are you basing your app on? Is this an official openshift cartridge?